# Android. Как задать перенос слова?

Tags: java, android, xml, текст, перенос

Заинтересовал такой вопрос. 
Есть ли готовые решения для пользовательского переноса слов в андроиде?
До сего дня, не было особой потребности в подобных ситуациях. 
Из готовых, не "велосипедных" решений, когда нужно было просто перенести слово, чтобы было более-менее читабельно использовал:

`android:breakStrategy="(balanced/high_quality/simple)"` -данное решение работает только с 23 
 API + часто вообще не срабатывает.
А так же
`android:hyphenationFrequency="(normal/full/none)"` 
пробовал как отдельно так и в комбинации с верхним решением, никак не влияет на результат. 
Сразу скажу, решение поставить другой размер шрифта или его позиционирование на баттоне мне не подходит, так как это не решает проблему, плюс к тому это скорее по теме дизайна.

Дабы было более понятнее, поясню на конкретном примере.

[image: скриншот]

В конкретной ситуации в баттоне с текстом  "TRANSLATE" я хочу чтобы переносило так.

TRANSLA-TE

Без вышеперечисленных способов с 23 API по дефолту переносит как на скриншоте.
(TRANSLAT-E)

C ними переносит так

TRANS-LATE

(притом одинаково при всех возможных сочетаниях этих методов)

Хочу понять, существуют ли нормальные рабочие решения в данном вопросе, особенно до 23 API. Поскольку варианты которые я находил либо вовсе не рабочие, либо криво работающие "велосипеды" на 100+ строк кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял из вопроса, проблема заключается в переносе текста на другую строку, если в **одной** он не помещается. Считаю, этот простой код решит Вашу проблему:

```
textView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean isNormal = false;
        String text = textView.getText().toString();
        String line1, line2;
        int length = text.length();
        int letterCount = 2; //Минимум букв для переноса - 2
        while (textView.getLineCount() > 1 && !isNormal) {
            if (letterCount < length) {
                line1 = text.substring(0, length-letterCount);
                line2 = text.substring(length-letterCount, length);
                textView.setText(line1 + "\n" + line2);
                if (yourCondition) isNormal = true;
                else letterCount++;
            } else break;
        };
    };
});
```

Можете настроить собственные параметры переноса, например "переносить только после гласной", проверяя последнюю букву в строке, и прочее.

**Update**

Решил всё-таки объяснить, как это будет работать и какие есть перспективы у моей модели переноса.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3948036) подтверждают, что всё переданное представлению с помощью метода `post()` будет выполнено после полной его отрисовки. Значит, когда система закончит подготавливать свои переносы строк, мы сможем изменить текст в соответствии со своими требованиями.

Так как предполагается всего две строки, их можно разбить, используя лишь один индекс. Так как количество строк никогда не уменьшится (если только не изменится размер самого представления) при перестановке букв, нужна логическая переменная, благодаря которой можно выйти из цикла.

При этом можно контролировать последнюю букву первой строки, и, как я написал выше, если нужно в первой строке оставить последней буквой гласную - проверяйте последнюю букву `line1`.